# Show messages based on Severity in two p:growl

Tags: primefaces, message, growl

I'm using PrimeFaces p:growl.

```
<p:growl id="msgsInfo"
         rendered="true"
         showDetail="true" />
<p:growl id="msgsError"
         globalOnly="true"
         showDetail="true"
         sticky="true" />
```

I need to show in the first growl only `Info` messages while in the second I need to show `Error` messages.
Using `globalOnly` when I add error message this is show 2 times.

Any idea?

Comment: Currently you can do. In fact, looks like it has been available for a time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465674/is-possible-use-tow-growls-in-one-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would in theory be possible if it supported `infoClass`, `errorClass`, etc attributes like as `h:messages`. You could then just specify a CSS class which does a `display: none`.

But the `p:growl` doesn't support those attributes. On the severity level all you can do is changing the icon by `infoIcon`, `errorIcon`, etc. So you're pretty lost here.

It might be worth a [feature request](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues).

Note that the `globalOnly="true"` only displays messages which have a `null` client ID, regardless of their severity.

Comment: Ok, also if i use rendered=message_severity?
I have think that but i'don't know how to implement

Comment: This won't work since that would apply on `p:growl` component itself, not on each of the messages it is displaying.

Answer (score 3):

Please see my answer

[PrimeFaces growl change color dynamically (Multiple messages)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40102625/1283636)

You can also find the source code of the project which produces the page below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same functionality (to set the growl to sticky from a specific message severity). PrimeFaces (6.1) doesn't offer this functionality, but it is quite easy to hack the [growl JavaScript](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_1/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/growl/growl.js). More specifically, in the `bindEvents` function they check if `sticky` was configured and based on that:

```
//hide the message after given time if not sticky
if(!sticky) {
    this.setRemovalTimeout(message);
}
```

So, you could prototype (override) the `bindEvents` function and set `sticky` based on the message severity.

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Growl.prototype.bindEvents = function(message) {
    var _self = this,
    sticky = this.cfg.sticky;

    // Start hack
    if (!sticky) {
      // Your rule
    }
    ...
```

You could also prototype `renderMessage` and add severity as a parameter to `bindEvents`. I chose to used a quick hack and read it from the `className`.

I've added these utility functions:

```
var SEVERITIES = [ "info", "warn", "error", "fatal" ];

function getSeverity(domNode) {
  // HACK Severity can be found in the className after the last - character.
  var severity = domNode.className;
  return severity.substring(severity.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
}

function getSeverityIndex(severityString) {
  return SEVERITIES.indexOf(severityString);
}
```

Now you can use the following check:

```
if (!sticky) {
  sticky = getSeverityIndex(getSeverity(message[0])) >= getSeverityIndex("error");
}
```

I might create a pull request at GitHub where you can set the minimum severity to stick massages using the `stickSeverity` attribute on the `p:growl` component.

Here is the full JavaScript hack (PrimeFaces 6.1):

```
var SEVERITIES = [ "info", "warn", "error", "fatal" ];

function getSeverity(domNode) {
  // HACK Severity can be found in the className after the last - character.
  var severity = domNode.className;
  return severity.substring(severity.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
}

function getSeverityIndex(severityString) {
  return SEVERITIES.indexOf(severityString);
}

PrimeFaces.widget.Growl.prototype.bindEvents = function(message) {
    var _self = this,
    sticky = this.cfg.sticky;

    // Start customization
    if (!sticky) {
      sticky = getSeverityIndex(getSeverity(message[0])) >= getSeverityIndex("error");
    }
    // End customization

    message.mouseover(function() {
        var msg = $(this);

        //visuals
        if(!msg.is(':animated')) {
            msg.find('div.ui-growl-icon-close:first').show();
        }
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        //visuals
        $(this).find('div.ui-growl-icon-close:first').hide();
    });

    //remove message on click of close icon
    message.find('div.ui-growl-icon-close').click(function() {
        _self.removeMessage(message);

        //clear timeout if removed manually
        if(!sticky) {
            clearTimeout(message.data('timeout'));
        }
    });

    //hide the message after given time if not sticky
    if(!sticky) {
        this.setRemovalTimeout(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth filing an enhancement in github

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm not sure if they will accept it. Probably they just say to use multiple growls and use the `severity` attribute.