# Growl Messages: show only error Messages stickable (JSF Primefaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, growl

I'm looking for a solution to display **only** *Error Messages* of a growl element in primefaces **stickable**. I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701102/show-messages-based-on-severity-in-two-pgrowl), but it is from Jan 2011. Are there any updates on this or another idea of someone?

I'm looking forward for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
<p:growl severity="error"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. You've answered my question.

Comment: remarkable that an answer with just code is accepted and an earlier answer with just a like but also some explanation is not but that one is upvoted

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at the new features in PrimeFaces 3.3.

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1894

There is now an attribute `severity` that allows you to specify only displaying messages of certain severity levels.