# is possible use two growls in one page

Tags: primefaces, growl

I want to use two growls in one page. One use to show success message that do  auto hide (`sticky="false")`, the other one use to show failed messages that do not auto hide (`sticky="true"`):

```
<p:growl id="globalSuccessMessageGrowl" showDetail="false"
        showSummary="true" life="3000" />

    <p:growl id="globalFailedMessageGrowl" showDetail="false"
        showSummary="true" sticky="true" />

public static void globalSuccessMessage(String message,
        FacesMessage.Severity severity) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("globalSuccessMessageGrowl"); 
    renderComponent(new FacesMessage(severity, message, message), null,
            "globalSuccessMessageGrowl");
}

public static void globalFailedMessage(String message,
        FacesMessage.Severity severity) {
    renderComponent(new FacesMessage(severity, message, message), null,
            "globalFailedMessageGrowl");
}
```

...but the two growls do not auto hide after 3 seconds. Failed growl effects success growls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show messages based on Severity in two p:growl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701102/show-messages-based-on-severity-in-two-pgrowl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign different severity levels to each one. This was an attribute added to primefaces in version 3.3.

Check [this](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17808) question . The user had the same problem as you do.