# How to change text color on p:growl according to severity?

Tags: jsf, dynamic, primefaces

I need to change the text color on `<p:growl>` according to severity, any idea?

I'm adding a programmatic growl in this method:

```
public void addMessageGrowl(Severity typeMessage, String detailMessage) {
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(typeMessage, "", detailMessage));
}
```

After I invoke this method:

```
addMessageGrowl(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "Ocurrió un error al ejecutar la operacion");
```

I however, want to customize the text color on the growl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change the text color, you can do this natively with the CSS sibbling selector:

```
.ui-growl-image-info ~ .ui-growl-message {
    color:#0f0;
}
.ui-growl-image-error ~ .ui-growl-message {
    color:#f00;
}
.ui-growl-image-warn~ .ui-growl-message {
    color:#00f;
}
.ui-growl-image-fatal~ .ui-growl-message {
    color:#000;
}
```

If you want to change the background to, you need something according to the link posted by @ÖmerFarukKurt:

[PrimeFaces growl change color dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877347/primefaces-growl-change-color-dynamically)

Comment: If you add more than one message to the context, let's say 2 (first one's severity info, the second one's danger) all growl elements will be the same (colored by the last message's severity -danger for our example). So the above solution is incorrect! Please see my answer...

Answer (score 2):

If you add more than one message at a time, the above solution will not work! (It will simply background-color by the last message's severity level)

You can find the corrent solution by following the link below

[PrimeFaces growl change color dynamically (Multiple messages)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40102625/1283636)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can solved this below link

[PrimeFaces growl change color dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877347/primefaces-growl-change-color-dynamically)